# What program currently handles the old notification area?

Tags: 11.04, unity, notification-area

With the removal of `notification-area`, what program now handles those few applications still using it?

My use case is the following: I have a legacy application in my start up applications that requires the notification area to be running before it can start up (otherwise I get an error about no system tray being around). Therefor I had written a little bash script that checked every few seconds whether `notification-area` was already in the running programs and if so, it would start up the program.

What program would be the new one to check for?

PS: I realize I could also add a `sleep` for *x* seconds and then just run the program regardless, but I see that as an ugly workaround.

Note: This question isn't about allowing the icon to be shown, I have set that setting to `all` the first day I started using Unity. This is about my program starting up **before** the program that handles the notification area and thus failing because there is simply no systray yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity actually is the program that runs the system tray. If you can read code, you may be able to see it for yourself [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/view/head:/src/PanelTray.cpp).

Supposedly [gnome-session 3](https://live.gnome.org/SessionManagement/NewGnomeSession) will automatically run startup in different phases so the panel & desktop would load before any applications which might fix your issue.

Comment: Based on this, I went on to assume that the process in question is `unity-panel-service`. Checking for this before starting up the program seems to be enough, but that could also be due to it simply starting up late enough. Either way, marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think gsettings handles it.

To enable the Notification Area (Systray) for all applications, run the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

for gui:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html)

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. gsettings is a backend for various settings for a program. What I want is the name of the program actually showing the notification icons. For example, `indicator-datetime` is the program that has to run to show the clock in the panel. Similarly there must be a program that runs to show those notification icons.

Comment: Ok. I see. I am not aware of that program. Having said that, I am using an application, davmail, which does not have updated app-indicator icons. The davmail icon only shows up if I set the gsettings to 'All'. This leads me to believe that whatever program is behind the notification, its still there, only restricted to show whitelisted applications.

Comment: Well, the program used to be called `notification-area` if I remember correctly, which now doesn't run at all. So there has been some change under the hood, it either got renamed or replaced by a similar program. That new name is the one I need.

Comment: `indicator-applet-complete` may be the one. The description here says " Indicator-applet is an applet to display information from
various applications consistently in the GNOME panel.

This instance will load all indicators in a single panel
applet."

Comment: Hang on! i think this one is more appropriate. `indicator-application` : A library and indicator to take menus from applications and place them in
the panel.

Comment: Lol guys - the program was not "notification-area" - it was the gnome-panel with an applet (XD!), and it used xembed to do it :P